# First array element that matches an element in another array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to return the first element in the given array that matches an element in a preset array. I have this:

```
def find_the_cheese(a)
  cheese_types = ["cheddar", "gouda", "camembert"]
  a.collect{|c| cheese_types.include?(c)}.include?(true)
end
```

But it returns `true` rather than the `c` value from the enclosed brackets. How can I return the matching element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array class includes the Enumerable module. [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) does just that:

```
def find_the_cheese(foods)
  cheeses = ["cheddar", "gouda", "camembert"]
  foods.find { |food| cheeses.include?(food) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code will returning elements from food which include in cheese_types

```
def find_the_cheese(food)
  cheese_types = ["cheddar", "gouda", "camembert"]
  food & cheese_types
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CheeseTypes = ["cheddar", "gouda", "camembert"]
def find_the_cheese(a)
  (a & CheeseTypes).first
end
```